# How can daylight have a higher colour temperature (e.g. 6500 K or D65) than sunlight in space?

Tags: optics, visible-light, scattering, atmospheric-science, absorption

Supposedly, daylight at midday has a colour temperature of [6500 K](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_temperature#The_Sun). This reference is also the standard for calibrating computer screens (that's how I fell into this). However, outside the atmosphere the sun has a colour temperature between 5770 and 5900 K.

I've looked everywhere I could, and nowhere is this difference explained, so I'm asking here.

I understand that (together with other effects) [Rayleigh scattering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_scattering) redirects blue light, and that as a result, the sun looks more yellow than in space, while when we look at the sky, we see the missing blue light.
However, a white object would receive both the direct sunlight as well as the diffused blue light, resulting in the same sum total. If anything, I would expect more blue light to be reflected into space and thus a lower colour temperature.

I did manage to find out about [Chappuis absorption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chappuis_absorption), which results in a blue sky during twilight, though it was never mentioned in the context of daylight. If I look at all absorption occuring in the atmosphere, as shown in [a typical solar spectrum diagram](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4c/Solar_Spectrum.png), blue light is actually absorbed more.

The only theory I could come up with myself is that light tangential to the earth could contribute, as some of its blue component is redirected to the earth while the remainder is not, but I find it hard to imagine that would have enough of an effect.

What's going on here?

Comment: [Daylight color temperature at noon is 5600K, but sunlight color temperature can vary widely based on time of day and weather conditions.](https://www.prolampsales.com/pages/color-temperature).

Comment: @JohnRennie directly above that quote daylight is given as 5000 - 6500 K, and I would very much like to know which weather conditions could cause a higher colour temperature =) Besides, I would not view that website as a quality source. In contrast, the [D65 standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Illuminant_D65) is an example of 6500 K as average daylight.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same question, and this is the only place I've seen someone else wondering about it! I have a hypothesis that might explain it.

Outside the atmosphere, the light hitting a point is coming directly from the sun, in a cone that is the angular diameter of the sun.

On Earth's surface, the direct sunlight is still coming in that same cone, but the diffuse skylight is coming from the entire sky; that is, sunlight in a much bigger cone is hitting the atmosphere, and some of that is being scattered toward the observer.

So basically the skylight is being collected over a much wider area than direct sunlight. And since the skylight is blue, that *could* explain why you can get (relatively) more blue light than in space. It depends on how exactly the amounts of scattering and absorption work out: only a small amount of light that's scattered reaches the observer, even though it is being collected over a wider area. That said, the light on the Earth's surface is only slightly bluer than light in space, so it could work out.

Obviously I don't have a full-fledged theory, or data to support it, but I suspect the answer lies somewhere in this direction.